# How to grab instagram content without browser request

Tags: ruby, instagram

There is a plenty of documentation on how to authenticate a user with some redirects, however if I just want to pull the content from Instagram, and display it in my application, how would I do that?

It looks like it's required only browser user redirection to pull the content

Comment: Are you talking about [Insagram's OAuth](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display instagram content as feeds in your web application you can just use

the javascript plugin ( jquery ) called instafeed to display feeds

http://instafeedjs.com/

If you want to enable instagram OAuth in your application you can use instagram ruby gem in the server side .

https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem